# Android : How can I get int value form service and set in text View on activity

Tags: android, android-service

My app has a countDown timer for 24 hours in his service. And show time in `TextView` any time even user left the app.

On service, i put an int number = 5184000. this is 24 hours converted to milliseconds;

**Problems:**

1. `TextView` don't show time in `Activity`.
2. I want to when timer equals 00:00:00, timer reset and new time equals 23:59:59.

**MainActiviy:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;
BroadcastReceiver broad;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);

    registerReceiver(broad, new IntentFilter(MyService.BROADCAST_ACTION));


    broad = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent intent1 = getIntent();
            Bundle bundle = intent1.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                int data = bundle.getInt("DDDD");
                tv.setText(data);
            } else {
                tv.setText("00:00:00");
            }
        }

     };
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

CountDownTimer cdt = null;
Intent intent1;
int h = 5184000;

public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.service";


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    cdt.cancel();
    Log.i("DDD", "Timer cancelled");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



    Log.i("TIME", "Starting timer...");

    cdt = new CountDownTimer(h, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            Log.i("TIME", "secondes: " + millisUntilFinished);

            intent1 = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
            intent1.putExtra("T", h);
            sendBroadcast(intent1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.i("TIME", "Timer finished");
        }
    };

    cdt.start();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
 }
}
```

**xml:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
    android:text="00:00:00"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: `5184000. this is 24 hours converted to milliseconds;` no it's not

Comment: @njzk2 Can you tell me why not?

Comment: Is your Broadcast Receiver's onReceive getting triggered? Have you tried to put  abreakpoint there?

Comment: @Anuj No, i don't put, i don't know about Broadcast. please edit my code.

Comment: because 24 hours in milliseconds is simply not 5184000. I don't see what is there to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Alarm Manager for that.

Check out below links for AlarmManager.

[AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

[Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)